# Unable to load fasttext-wiki-news-subswords-300

Tags: api, gensim, fasttext

Starting with the gensim api:

```
import gensim.downloader as api
api.load('fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300')
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user.name/gensim-data/fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300/fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300.gz'
```

I also tried the cli:

```
python3 -m gensim.downloader --download fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300
```

and when I check the `~/gensim-data/fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300` folder it only contains:

```
__init__.py
__pycache__
```

Have there been any changes to the to api or the dataset in the last few months?

**Note**

I am using `Python3.8` and `gensim==4.2.0`

I have checked that the Certificates are Installed ('Install Certificates.command').

Comment: Is that the full & complete error messag, including any 'traceback' showing involved lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting the `~/gensim-data` folder and downgraded `gensim` to `3.8.3`, seems to be working now. Leaving the question and answer here as (1) error message was a red herring and (2) solution was not straightforward.